# Dashed line in Line plus bar chart NVD3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, highcharts, nvd3.js

I have added a line in line plus bar chart in NVD3. but i want that added single line in dashed format.

How to do it in linePlusBar chart.[image]

As shown in image Limit line I added but i want this line to be doted or dashed.

Please help me out, how to do it??

[image]

As shown in above graph i want orange line to be dashed.
how to do it??

```
<script>


    var chart;
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart().margin({
            top : 50,
            right : 80,
            bottom : 30,
            left : 80
        }).legendRightAxisHint(' [Using Right Axis]').color(
                d3.scale.category10().range()).options({
            focusEnable : false
        });

        chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
        }).showMaxMin(false);

        chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(function(d) {
            return '$' + d3.format(',f')(d)
        });
        chart.bars.forceY([ 0 ]).padData(false);

        chart.x2Axis.tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
        }).showMaxMin(false);

        d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(testdata).transition().duration(500)
                .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) {
            nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e));
        });

        return chart;
    });
</script>
```

Data as follows:

```
var testdata = [
            {
                "key" : "Quantity",
                "bar" : true,
                "values" : [ [ 1136005200000, 1271000.0 ],
                        [ 1138683600000, 1271000.0 ],
                        [ 1141102800000, 1271000.0 ], [ 1143781200000, 0 ],
                        [ 1146369600000, 0 ], [ 1149048000000, 0 ],
                        [ 1151640000000, 0 ], [ 1154318400000, 0 ],
                        [ 1156996800000, 0 ], [ 1159588800000, 3899486.0 ],
                        [ 1162270800000, 3899486.0 ],
                        [ 1164862800000, 3899486.0 ],
                        [ 1167541200000, 3564700.0 ],
                        [ 1170219600000, 3564700.0 ],
                        [ 1172638800000, 3564700.0 ],
                        [ 1175313600000, 2648493.0 ],
                        [ 1177905600000, 2648493.0 ],
                        [ 1180584000000, 2648493.0 ],
                        [ 1183176000000, 2522993.0 ],
                        [ 1185854400000, 2522993.0 ],
                        [ 1188532800000, 2522993.0 ],
                        [ 1191124800000, 2906501.0 ],
                        [ 1193803200000, 2906501.0 ],
                        [ 1196398800000, 2906501.0 ],
                        [ 1199077200000, 2206761.0 ],
                        [ 1201755600000, 2206761.0 ],
                        [ 1204261200000, 2206761.0 ],
                        [ 1206936000000, 2287726.0 ],
                        [ 1209528000000, 2287726.0 ],
                        [ 1212206400000, 2287726.0 ],
                        [ 1214798400000, 2732646.0 ],
                        [ 1217476800000, 2732646.0 ],
                        [ 1220155200000, 2732646.0 ],
                        [ 1222747200000, 2599196.0 ],
                        [ 1225425600000, 2599196.0 ],
                        [ 1228021200000, 2599196.0 ],
                        [ 1230699600000, 1924387.0 ],
                        [ 1233378000000, 1924387.0 ],
                        [ 1235797200000, 1924387.0 ],
                        [ 1238472000000, 1756311.0 ],
                        [ 1241064000000, 1756311.0 ],
                        [ 1243742400000, 1756311.0 ],
                        [ 1246334400000, 1743470.0 ],
                        [ 1249012800000, 1743470.0 ],
                        [ 1251691200000, 1743470.0 ],
                        [ 1254283200000, 1519010.0 ],
                        [ 1256961600000, 1519010.0 ],
                        [ 1259557200000, 1519010.0 ],
                        [ 1262235600000, 1591444.0 ],
                        [ 1264914000000, 1591444.0 ],
                        [ 1267333200000, 1591444.0 ],
                        [ 1270008000000, 1543784.0 ],
                        [ 1272600000000, 1543784.0 ],
                        [ 1275278400000, 1543784.0 ],
                        [ 1277870400000, 1309915.0 ],
                        [ 1280548800000, 1309915.0 ],
                        [ 1283227200000, 1309915.0 ],
                        [ 1285819200000, 1331875.0 ],
                        [ 1288497600000, 1331875.0 ],
                        [ 1291093200000, 1331875.0 ],
                        [ 1293771600000, 1331875.0 ],
                        [ 1296450000000, 1154695.0 ],
                        [ 1298869200000, 1154695.0 ],
                        [ 1301544000000, 1194025.0 ],
                        [ 1304136000000, 1194025.0 ],
                        [ 1306814400000, 1194025.0 ],
                        [ 1309406400000, 1194025.0 ],
                        [ 1312084800000, 1194025.0 ],
                        [ 1314763200000, 1244525.0 ],
                        [ 1317355200000, 475000.0 ],
                        [ 1320033600000, 475000.0 ],
                        [ 1322629200000, 475000.0 ],
                        [ 1325307600000, 690033.0 ],
                        [ 1327986000000, 690033.0 ],
                        [ 1330491600000, 690033.0 ],
                        [ 1333166400000, 514733.0 ],
                        [ 1335758400000, 514733.0 ] ]
            },
            {
                "key" : "Limit",
                "values" : [ [ 1136005200000, 500 ], [ 1335758400000, 500 ] ],
                classed : 'dashed'
            },
            {
                "key" : "Price",
                "values" : [ [ 1136005200000, 71.89 ],
                        [ 1138683600000, 75.51 ], [ 1141102800000, 68.49 ],
                        [ 1143781200000, 62.72 ], [ 1146369600000, 70.39 ],
                        [ 1149048000000, 59.77 ], [ 1151640000000, 57.27 ],
                        [ 1154318400000, 67.96 ], [ 1156996800000, 67.85 ],
                        [ 1159588800000, 76.98 ], [ 1162270800000, 81.08 ],
                        [ 1164862800000, 91.66 ], [ 1167541200000, 84.84 ],
                        [ 1170219600000, 85.73 ], [ 1172638800000, 84.61 ],
                        [ 1175313600000, 92.91 ], [ 1177905600000, 99.8 ],
                        [ 1180584000000, 121.191 ],
                        [ 1183176000000, 122.04 ],
                        [ 1185854400000, 131.76 ],
                        [ 1188532800000, 138.48 ],
                        [ 1191124800000, 153.47 ],
                        [ 1193803200000, 189.95 ],
                        [ 1196398800000, 182.22 ],
                        [ 1199077200000, 198.08 ],
                        [ 1201755600000, 135.36 ],
                        [ 1204261200000, 125.02 ],
                        [ 1206936000000, 143.5 ],
                        [ 1209528000000, 173.95 ],
                        [ 1212206400000, 188.75 ],
                        [ 1214798400000, 167.44 ],
                        [ 1217476800000, 158.95 ],
                        [ 1220155200000, 169.53 ],
                        [ 1222747200000, 113.66 ],
                        [ 1225425600000, 107.59 ],
                        [ 1228021200000, 92.67 ], [ 1230699600000, 85.35 ],
                        [ 1233378000000, 90.13 ], [ 1235797200000, 89.31 ],
                        [ 1238472000000, 105.12 ],
                        [ 1241064000000, 125.83 ],
                        [ 1243742400000, 135.81 ],
                        [ 1246334400000, 142.43 ],
                        [ 1249012800000, 163.39 ],
                        [ 1251691200000, 168.21 ],
                        [ 1254283200000, 185.35 ],
                        [ 1256961600000, 188.5 ],
                        [ 1259557200000, 199.91 ],
                        [ 1262235600000, 210.732 ],
                        [ 1264914000000, 192.063 ],
                        [ 1267333200000, 204.62 ],
                        [ 1270008000000, 235.0 ],
                        [ 1272600000000, 261.09 ],
                        [ 1275278400000, 256.88 ],
                        [ 1277870400000, 251.53 ],
                        [ 1280548800000, 257.25 ],
                        [ 1283227200000, 243.1 ],
                        [ 1285819200000, 283.75 ],
                        [ 1288497600000, 300.98 ],
                        [ 1291093200000, 311.15 ],
                        [ 1293771600000, 322.56 ],
                        [ 1296450000000, 339.32 ],
                        [ 1298869200000, 353.21 ],
                        [ 1301544000000, 348.5075 ],
                        [ 1304136000000, 350.13 ],
                        [ 1306814400000, 347.83 ],
                        [ 1309406400000, 335.67 ],
                        [ 1312084800000, 390.48 ],
                        [ 1314763200000, 384.83 ],
                        [ 1317355200000, 381.32 ],
                        [ 1320033600000, 404.78 ],
                        [ 1322629200000, 382.2 ], [ 1325307600000, 405.0 ],
                        [ 1327986000000, 456.48 ],
                        [ 1330491600000, 542.44 ],
                        [ 1333166400000, 599.55 ],
                        [ 1335758400000, 583.98 ] ]
            } ]
```

Comment: can you give afiddle

Comment: you can style it up...can you please paste the code..

Comment: Yess!! I pasted my code pls help me. I cant paste testData pls consider me and help me its very urgent.

Comment: and data as well..the trick is to inspect the line and add the style to it.

Comment: Hello Cyril, I added data as well. I added line Limit. I want data of limit as dashed or doted how to do it?? please help me.

Comment: sry bro i cannot make this on the punk so cannot help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with CSS. For instance if you wanted the **2nd** line dashed:

```
<style>
  .nv-series-1>path {
    stroke-dasharray: 3,3;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Hii! Mark! Thanks for reply.. Thank you it works fine.

Comment: Hii!! Mark!! I want bar as stacked bar. can we do that and how?